# Adding a preloaded image into HTML using an img tag causes the image to re-download

Tags: jquery

On load, I am preloading several images, using the following:

```
var temp = '<img src="'+image_src+'" />',
    target = '#'+currentId;     

$(temp).on('load', function() {
    $(target).data('loaded','y');
});
```

Then, when I need to call the image, I am adding it to the document with:

```
var $image = '<img src="'+image_src+'" />';

$('.image-container').html($image);
```

Monitoring this in developer tools, I am seeing that the images are preloaded correctly, but then appear to also be loaded again when they are added into the document.

I had believed that by preloading the image src, it would add this from the browser cache when added into the html.

Is this correct, or are images downloaded again, if added in the above way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're creating two separate `<img />` elements. The first one you create in-memory and perform the preload on. The second one you create entirely separately and append to `.image-container` within the DOM.

To fix the issue, just append the first one which was preloaded in to `.image-container`. Also note that it would make most sense to perform the `append()` within the `load()` event handler, as that way you can be certain that the image has been loaded.

```js
var image_src = 'https://i.imgur.com/RVAJHpS.png';
var $img = $('<img src="' + image_src + '" />');
var $target = $('#target');

$img.on('load', function() {
  $target.data('loaded', 'y');
  $('.image-container').append($img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
<div class="image-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory for taking the time to show me my mistake! I finally 'get it'!